# Should hot water heater pipes in the basement be insulated?

Tags: water-circulating-heating

I have a Gambrel style home with gas fired baseboard hotwater system.  The hotwater pipes in the basement are located to the outside wall. These pipes are not wrapped in insulation.  Would wrapping the pipes be advised?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where in the world are you located? What's your climate like? Is your basement wall insulated?

Comment: If you want the basement to be cold, say for wine storage, then it's a good idea, but it won't matter too much for upstairs. You get most of that basement heat back eventually as hot air rises, so heat-pipe wrapping is not a huge efficiency improvement except in drastic cases like long runs along a thin wall in alaska...

Answer (score 1):

I've done it in my basement, otherwise you are just heating the basement, which is typically not conditioned.   You can use the split foam insulation that's preformed, and cover as much as you can.

Comment: If you do insulate the heating pipes, don't forget to insulate the return pipes too.  If the basement gets below freezing, they might have been relying on the warmth from the hot pipes to stop them freezing.